# OAuth2.0 Library Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, oauth-2.0, portable-class-library

I am searching for a library like Xamarin.Auth which is supporting not only android and iOS. I need support for all platforms like OsX, iOS, android and Windows Dekstop apps.

Is there something on the market?

Comment: You  want one library to write once code for both mobile and desktop apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library is not complete but it is super super easy to extend. You basically just need to write the webview for Windows/OSX and you will be good to go. And I do accept pull requests! https://github.com/clancey/simpleauth